# Type guard for Object (is not null)

Tags: typescript, typeguards

How could I get a type guard for an *object* right in TypeScript?

I have a checking function for any input:

```
export function isObject(input: any) :input is Record<string,any> {
     return (input !== null) && (typeof input === 'object');
}
```

But when I use it like this, the compiler does not see my checked variable as the needed type:

```
const constants = {};
const haveConstantsObj = isObject(constants);

// for constants: Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
if (haveConstantsObj && !constants.householdType) {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I am not sure why you even have a type guard in the first place here. `constants` is declared with a `const`, so there is no chance it can be `null`. Is this a simplified example? If not, you can simply provide with the declaration: `const constants: Record<string,any> = {};`. Better still, isn't it better to make `constants` implement an interface `interface Consts { householdType ?: <your type here> }`?

Comment: @OlegValter this example is simplyfied, yes. `constants` is actually filled with data asynchronously and I need to check, whether it is present at all. A less abstract type might help here, but not for the the necessary check against smth like `isObject`.

Comment: Thought so, thanks for clarifying -  btw, is there a chance the `constants` object can be of a type other than `null` or `object`? Wanted to suggest using an inline `if(constants)` guard to simplify things, but you already mentioned it in the comments (as far as I recall, the handbook encourages inline guards where possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is a bit finicky at times.

Instead of saving the result of `isObject` to a variable, include it in the same `if` check and it works.

```
export function isObject(input: any) :input is Record<string,any> {
     return (input !== null) && (typeof input === 'object');
} 

const constants = {};
if (isObject(constants) && !constants.householdType) {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwHkAjAK2AwApMUwkYAuOAQxQE8BKOBmu+AuACUK0ACYAefDCg0A5gBpWbAHxwA3gFgAUHF26owGEii5qtenACEAXmtwUSADaOuAMldxKMNmGAQEeObwtnYA5BBkFDChHADc2gC+cNraaDhScGkoUqww+HB2agnxWgD0pYjQmekwufhMJOQYePmQ+PiYxI5scKEOzqEAdHmUAEwArADMAIwc2pgB1ESRVFk5KHluHpZrtRv4gwAWEEj4wMeOogAqPsBcmjp6axCOwIOOELKUoYfAbDElBJAA)

Comment: Would there be a benefit to this instead of using the non-null assertion and defining `constants` as an object? (I still fight occasional TS type.)

Comment: @DaveNewton This syntax is most valuable when you have a concrete type vs. something flexible like a `Record`. So if `input` was `string | { householdType: boolean }`, this code structure makes a lot more sense, as you get compile time safety and you only have `housholdType` when `isObject` is truthy.

Comment: When I think about it: maybe I should shift away from the *Underscore* way of type checking for TypeScript. All I need to know here is `constants !== null && constants !== undefined`. Or simply `if (constants) ...` I just don't like those general checks and for me it still makes sense to wrap this sort of checking in a function, but if the compiler does not know, what I am knowing with this check, it does not help.

Comment: *Instead of saving the result of isObject to a variable, include it in the same if check and it works.* Is there any reason for this interesting behavior?

Comment: @BairDev - it all comes down to code flow analysis. Type guards return type predicates - assertions about a type of a variable. At the same time, control statements such as `if` guarantee that something is true while inside their scope. This allows TS to safely narrow the type. Now, when you assign a result of calling a guard to a variable, the only thing that can be guaranteed at *compile* time is that the variable is now of type `boolean`. Now the control statement cannot guarantee the variable is of a certain type inside it at *compile* time.

Comment: Yes, as Oleg says, it *is* in the if and *is not* in the else. Anywhere else the type is not certain. There is nothing wrong with this, and can be very valuable in some cases. See [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) for more details.